# Is there any cookie system on samsung smart tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I want to store my smarttv aplication's status. Example: I have a multipaged document and I want to store where the user left the program to open this page when the user reopens the program.

What is the efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: yeah you see i don't know how to write a file, and don't have any idea what the google is. at least give me the link you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are talking about pages and cookies, I'll assume you are using the HTML / JavaScript API.

According to [Samsung's list of JavaScript properties](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/References/Browser_Specifications/JavaScript), the `cookie` property is supported. This is defined in the [DOM Level 1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html) and Quirks Mode has [a guide to using cookies from JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. I couldn't see anyone using cookies on smart TV apps, mostly they prefer text files but cookies are easier i think. Sorry for the trouble. Accessing Samsung smart TV documents is a total pain for me.

Comment: BBC iPlayer uses cookies to store user preferences on Samsung TVs.

Comment: Got to be careful though, on some Samsung Smart TV devices such as their Blu-ray players, the cookie cache can often be cleared out when the device goes into standby.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official Samsung SDK to save a small quantity of data on the persistent memory of the device.

[SDK: localData](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.1/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/AppsFramework_APIs/Framework_API/Core_API/sf.core/localData)

This API allow you to save and read a value:

```
# saves current page state
sf.core.localData("currentPage", "home");

# reads current page state
var previousPage = sf.core.localData("currentPage");
```

Otherwise you can use the readFile API:

[SDK: readFile](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.1/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/AppsFramework_APIs/Framework_API/Core_API/sf.core/readFile)